No results to fetch(python, psql)
Выдает ошибку No results to fetch при попытке вывести данные таблицы (СУБД psql), хотя в таблице данных много и выводить есть что. при этом если убрать часть с if, попытавшись вывести данные без изменений до этого, то все выводит шикарно.
код собственно
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    database = "new",
    user = "ganzzaz",
    password = "12345"
    )
print ("connection ready")
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("cursor ready")
postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from table1"

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
print("what to add new data? Y/N")
a=input()
if a == "Y":
    newname = input("name")
    newage = input("age")
    new_data = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, age) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    datatouse = (newname, newage)
    cursor.execute(new_data, datatouse)
    conn.commit()
    an = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    print(an)


ну так после своего инсерта попробуйте опять селект сделать
